# Is It ok to pass iterable[i] instead of iterable.length in loops

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

Should there be any concern of using

```
for(let i = 0; iterable[i];i++)
```

instead of

```
for(let i = 0; i < iterable.length; i++)
```

Comment: It will work if iterable[i] is truthy (like if it's an object or array it will be fine) but the loop will stop (possibly unexpectedly) if iterable[i] is a falsy value like 0, empty string, false, etc.  The loop will also stop if iterable[i] is undefined (the end of the loop).

Comment: No, you cannot use your 1st construct. Since it's behavior could be very different than the 2nd.

Comment: You may use [`for-of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) construct to traverse iterables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not safe to write `iterable[i]` instead of `i < iterable.length` because the first method will check if `iterable[i]` is truthy or falsy and in javascript there are `6` falsy values. `null, undefined, 0, '', NaN, false`.

Consider you have array of numbers or strings and you use `iterable[i]` as loop condition. Then the loop will exit at empty string or `0`. Also this way will cause serious issues while iterating over array of booleans.

But if you are looping over array of objects or array of another arrays then most probably it will not cause any problem but I will prefer to you use `i < iterable.length`.

Comment: Array of objects can have null elements.

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes but here we are not considering that null is an object. Here I am only talking about instance of `Object`

Comment: I'm using it to loop in HTML element.children which I don't think it can be falsy unless there is no more children, Am I correct ?